# Unable to boot DD'd Windows 10 drive

Tags: boot, windows, dd

Booted into SystemRescueCD and with a USB to SATA adaptor attached to the PC issued the command `dd if=/dev/sda of=/dev/sdb status=progress`. A few hours later I had what looked from partitions shown in Linux's `fdisk` to be an exact duplicate of the original drive. However when selecting this drive, still connected to the PC via the USB to SATA adaptor, in BIOS as the first boot device when the boot process gets to the stage an OS is launched the screen gets stuck for presumably ever on a blank screen with a flashing cursor top left. The original HDD booted before and after this test with compatible UEFI turned on and secure boot turned off (as was set when DD was used).

Have read elsewhere that the system reserved partition needs to be marked as active, but this seems to only apply to MBR boot sectors according to Windows' `diskpart`. Also that `bcdboot <windows location> /s <drive with bcd to repair>` needs to be run, but that didn't change the symptoms when done.

Find below screenshot of the partitions and status for the original HDD first (Disk 0), and then the copy second (Disk 1).

What am I missing?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Cross posted [on SU](https://superuser.com/q/1662345/432690). I'm voting to close this copy here on U&L.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski Ironically the first activity this post has gotten in almost 5 days. I noted the cross post on the SU page. Given it clearly transects Linux and Windows knowledge, I had hoped it could stay in both for some time, to give the maximum chance someone will see it and provide there thoughts.

Comment: "it clearly transects Linux and Windows knowledge" – I'm not so sure the Linux part is significant. But even if it is… regardless if it is, the Windows part is significant for sure. Problems with Windows are off-topic here, while Windows and Linux are *both* on-topic on Super User. IMO the question belongs to SU from the very beginning. I don't want to destroy your question; I want to close an excessive *copy* of it. And I hope SU will solve the problem. You have already got few useful technical comments there because Windows guys sit there, not here.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski - If not BIOS I know the issue exists with how Windows is booting, and therefore the fix is Windows related, but maybe someone using dd to do this in the past has found the gotcha I am missing and can provide something to try. Linux did something that Windows can't work with, or didn't do something that Windows needs that Windows tools would have, is the other perspective. Given I have seen far less Linux solutions, or questions, on SU compared to here, I was hoping to get a Linux person to comment. Finally, if Linux questions are in scope in SU, why does this subsite exist?

Comment: I'm not going to argue. I believe Windows does not support booting from USB. Linux has nothing to do with the fact Windows is limited.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski I know Windows does boot from USB. The PE environment, a cutdown version of Windows, offers USB drive as an option to boot it on Windows' webpages. I have also booted full Windows off USB a number of times before (probably using MBR), as has others given my reference to marking the system reserved partition as active after cloning. A Linux tool was used to clone the drive, and whether it is the direct cause, or whether it is a byproduct of it's operation, it still has to do with Linux, given dd (or a wrapper) could be offered to solve whatever Windows is being picky about.